# A wallet for coins, using weight to display the contents value?

Tags: combinatorics

In England common goverment produced coins are:

1p (3.56g), 2p (7.12g), 5p (3.25g), 10p (6.5g), 20p (5g), 50p (8g), £1 (9.5g) and £2 (12g)

They have different weights, but I think coins of the same type should have the same weight as each other.

Can the value of the coins be calculated from the total weight? If so then how?

For example: 16g total would presumably have to contain two 50p coins, whereas 22.5g would also contain a 10p.

Comment: What is the weight of a 20p coin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A wallet containing 48 grams could be worth 8 GBP  (four two-pound coins) or 3 GBP (six times 50p). What you want would be possible if the weights are either rationally independant or proportional to the value (the latter is the case with 1p and 2p, so if you know that only those coins are involved then the value can be detemrined from the weight, but not the number of coins used).

In the lack of rational independnce / in the view of measurement errors and production tolerances, the best we can get is that the weight determines the value *provided* it is below some limit (which, as seen above, is certainly at most 48g for British money).

Comment: Or, dividing your example by 2, we see the upper limit is at most 24g.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving 'Hagen's answer as the correct one, but now I'm thinking about this correctly, TY Hagen, I can add some more thoughts that is probably best done as an answer like this.

The problem being that any two rational numbers will share multiples.

So weights like 5g, 1/3g or 1.234g won't work in all situations, unless as Hagen states weights are proportional to value.

20p (1g), 50p (Πg), £1 (√2g), £2 (1.1010010001...g) might work.